# R extracting non-missing data

Tags: r, missing-data

I have a dataframe:

```
a<-c(1,2,3)
b<-c("CarA","CarB",NA)
data<-data.frame(a,b)

data

    a    b
  1 1 CarA
  2 2 CarB
  3 3   NA
```

Now I want to remove the row with missing data (NA).

But this does not work:

```
data<-data[data[,2]!=NA,]
```

My thinking here is to look at the second column [,2] and look for those that don't have NA.  Then extract the remaining data.  Would someone be able to tell me what went wrong here?

Comment: `?na.omit` can be useful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't

```
na.omit(data)
```

do? It seems the cleanest and fastest way to me.

By the way, your code does not work because you cannot do `!=NA`

Use `is.na()` instead (but `na.omit()` is better):

```
data[!is.na(data[,2]),]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want some other answer check complete.cases

```
  data[complete.cases(data),]
```